# Aggregate static libraries

Tags: c, static-libraries

I try to aggregate multiple .a files into a single one. The command is the following:

```
TARGET=libnumpy.a
DIR=build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/numpy
FILES=$(DIR)/core/_sort.a $(DIR)/core/multiarray.a $(DIR)/core/umath.a $(DIR)/core/scalarmath.a $(DIR)/core/umath_tests.a $(DIR)/core/multiarray_tests.a $(DIR)/lib/_compiled_base.a $(DIR)/numarray/_capi.a $(DIR)/fft/fftpack_lite.a $(DIR)/linalg/lapack_lite.a $(DIR)/random/mtrand.a

all:
    ar cr $(TARGET) $(FILES)
```

But the resulting library libnumpy.a is unusable. When trying to compile something with it, I get

```
libnumpy.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
```

(I tried to run ranlib but it didn't solve the problem)

When doing nm libnumpy.a I get

```
nm: _sort.a: File format not recognized
nm: multiarray.a: File format not recognized
nm: umath.a: File format not recognized 
nm: scalarmath.a: File format not recognized
nm: umath_tests.a: File format not recognized
nm: multiarray_tests.a: File format not recognized
nm: _compiled_base.a: File format not recognized
nm: _capi.a: File format not recognized
nm: fftpack_lite.a: File format not recognized
nm: lapack_lite.a: File format not recognized
nm: mtrand.a: File format not recognized
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mat mentioned:

```
#ar x <archivefile>  / * Repeat for all archives */
#ar cv <all Obj fiels>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're adding archive files to an archive file. You shouldn't be doing that, you should be putting object files in an archive.

One way around that if you have GNU `ar` is to create thin archives (with the `T` switch):

> GNU ar can optionally create a thin archive, which contains a symbol index and references to the original copies of the member
>          files of the archives.  Such an archive is useful for building libraries for use within a local build, where the relocatable
>          objects are expected to remain available, and copying the contents of each object would only waste time and space.  **Thin
>          archives are also flattened, so that adding one or more archives to a thin archive will add the elements of the nested archive
>          individually.**  The paths to the elements of the archive are stored relative to the archive itself.

Otherwise, archive all the individual `.o` files that comprise your original `.a` files.