# c static library linux

Tags: c, linux, static-libraries

I want to make a static library and was able to make one properly by following the yolinux tutorial
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

The issue arises when i want to include a static library to make a new static library.
    Scenario is:

```
gcc -Wall -c cdbSearch.c
ar -cvq cdbSrc.a cdbSearch.o cdb.a
```

this successfully creates a static library named cdbSrc.a

but when I try to link this with my test program

```
gcc -o cdbtest cdbtest.c cdbSrc.a
cdbSrc.a(cdbSearch.o): In function `cdb_search':
cdbSearch.c:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `cdb_seek'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

it gives me an error saying that cdb_seek cant be referenced which is actually a part of cdb.a

and if I compile the test program with cdb.a it works fine but then it does not serve the purpose..

```
gcc -o cdbtest cdbtest.c cdbSrc.a cdb.a
```

and the binary is created cdbtest successfully.

is this the intended behaviour, is yes why?? and if not than what am I doing wrong..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aggregate static libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547061/aggregate-static-libraries)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is the intended behavior. You need to link all static libraries to form a binary. Static libraries unlike shared libraries will not hold the link to other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Static library is just archive of object files. You must unpack cdb.a by using `ar x`

And after that, pack all unpacked objects plus cdbSearch.o into cdbSrc.a

Comment: You can do this just for checing purpose. But, it is better to keep unrelated features in seperate libraries as it helps in better maintainence.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a new static library, which should contain `cdbSearch.o` and all the object files in `cdb.a` right.

I assumed like `cdb.a` is having two object files, which are `first.o` and `second.o`.

`ar` allows to add object files to an existing static library. You can execute the below command for that.

`ar r cdb.a cdbSearch.o`

If a library named `cdb.a` presents then the above command will add the new object file `cdbSearch.o` into that. Or else it will create new static library `cdb.a` which will contains only one object file(`cdbSearch.o`).

Now `cdb.a` will contains 3 objects files(`first.o`, `second.o` and `cdbSearch.o`). Now you can rename the static library file name if you want, `mv cdb.a cdbSrc.a`.

We can delete any existing object file from a static library also by using `d` option. For example if you want to delete the object file `second.o` from `cdbSrc.a` you can execute the below command.

`ar d cdbSrc.a second.o`

Use the `t` option to list the object files of a static library.

`ar t cdbSrc.a`